# wordpress admin settings permalinks redirects to front page

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Just cloned my site from the dev domain to the live domain using MainWP. Normally after logging in the first step is to go and reset the permalinks. For some random reason /wp-admin/options-permalink.php keeps redirecting me to the front page of the site. Have looked and looked for a solution and it seems nobody else has had this problem.

Anybody have a clue as to what I should do?

I have tried deleting the .htaccess file. When that didn't work I recreated it with the default one for wordpress. I also edited the misc.php file as suggested in a similar question, which was to include `$got_rewrite = true;` in the got_mod_rewrite function.

I also deactivated several plugins that have anything to do with caching or redirects.

Comment: I ended up loading the site in a different browser and then everything worked fine. Only other thing I had done was reactivate all the plugins again. Guess there was no major issue. I'd delete this question except there may be others out there who are also not considering something simple like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand this problem this issue related to link mapping.

please check your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

if it's not look like this make it one.

also,.htaccess in WordPress all you need is to delete this file and then enter wp-admin -> settings > permalinks > save.

and also, try to clear your browser's cache, it was caching files so it used the old copy may be.

Comment: now I feel stupid. It was the browser cache it seems. But just to clarify, I could not get to wp-admin -> settings > permalinks. That would always chuck me to the front page of the site.
I opened a different browser and logged into the site and it worked fine. Can't believe I didn't think of that. It's been a long year...

Comment: it's okay the problem is slove is more important ;)